# Length of Values Not Matching Length of Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison, cryptocurrency

I am doing some cryptocurrency analysis utilizing the Pandas library for Python. I have produced the following dataframe:

```
        coin    old_price      current_price
0     BNBBTC    0.000949            0.000994
1     BNBETH    0.011472            0.012129
2    BNBUSDT   10.938950            9.358000
3     VENBNB    0.619480            0.635200
```

Then, I am attempting to compare the two columns old_price and current_price.

Upon using this line of code below:

```
comparison['sell'] = np.where((comparison['current_price'] >= comparison['old_price']))
```

I am receive an error stating:

```
"ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index"
```

To the best of my knowledge, the dataframe has the same number of data for each column. Please advise, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: @DyZ - corrected df to be comparison - it is of the same shape as the other columns in the comparison dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.where(condition)` without the second and third optional arguments returns the array of row indexes for which the `condition` is `True`. This array in general is shorter than the original DataFrame (in your case, it has only one value):

```
np.where(comparison['current_price'] >= comparison['old_price'])
#(array([2]),)
```

What you need is probably this:

```
comparison['sell'] = (comparison['current_price'] >= comparison['old_price'])
#array([False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Worked - thank you for the solution and the added explanation.